# Correct Theoretical Discount Factors from Nelson-Siegel-Svensson?

Tags: fixed-income, programming, bond

I am calculating the theoretical discount factors associated with a bond that has 30 months to maturity from today with the parameters below obtained from [here](http://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/researchdata/feds200628_1.html) using the  Nelson-Siegel-Svensson Model. The Python code is just a direct application of the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson Model formula. *Are the theoretical Discount factors obtained from NSS meant to be this small?*

```
beta_0 = 6.33120453
beta_1 =-6.22139731
beta_2 = -4.55116776
beta_3 = -8.72097716
tau_1 = 1.68437012
tau_2 = 11.18918219
months_to_maturity_array = numpy.array([6, 12, 18, 24, 30])
years_to_maturity_array = months_to_maturity_array/12
term_1 = (beta_0) + (beta_1*((1-numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))/(years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))) + (beta_2*((((1-numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))/(years_to_maturity_array/tau_1)))-(numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_1))) + (beta_3*((((1-numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_2))/(years_to_maturity_array/tau_2)))-(numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array/tau_2))))
test = numpy.exp(-years_to_maturity_array * (term_1))
print('RESULT:', test)
```

The output discount factors come out to be `[ 0.9032555   0.70209724  0.44987297  0.23612997  0.10293834]`, which seems very low. Such small discount factors will result in very small prices as expected, which effects the Non-Linear Optimization used to calculate the parameters. For example if the bond has the set of coupons and face values as shown below, then the `price` turns out to be `27.2861601745`.

```
coupons_and_facevals = [1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 102.5]          
coupons_and_facevals = numpy.array(coupons_and_facevals)
price = 0
for i in range(0,4,1):
    price = price + coupons_and_facevals[i] * test[i]
```

I've been dabbling with this for a while but am stuck.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `term_1`, which represent the zero coupon rates, are expressed in %. You have to divide the values by 100 to compute discount factors.

Comment: Thank You. Just to be sure, I just need to divide `term_1` by 100?

Comment: Yes. Also, make sure you put `months_to_maturity_array/12.0` instead of `months_to_maturity_array/12`.